# How can I render latitude-longitude coordinates on a map with D3?

Tags: cartography, latitude-longitude, maps, d3

I am trying to overlay dots of arbitrary sets of longitude-latitude coordinates on top of a United States map.

So far I have found the [D3 cartography example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cartogram.html), but when I try to place dots on X,Y pixel coordinates they appear way off the canvas.  I did find [workshot lecture notes which include coordinate systems in d3](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/d3/workshop/), but I'm still unsure of how get lat/long coords to show up on the map.

[This is what I have so far](http://jaytaylor.com/d3/examples/cartogram/cartogram.html) (pretty much only a map of the USA)

Advice on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: d3 is svg correct?

Comment: Yes, d3 is svg.

Comment: A good example of rendering svg to map is here - https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/wiki/Rendering-SVG-maps-from-OpenStreetMap-data using Path and Measures

Answer (score 16):

You need to have a projection() function to project the lat and long of your points onto the map. By default, a d3 geo path uses the albersUsa projection, so you could declare it explicitly:

```
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa();
```

You'll see this done in examples that don't use AlbersUsa, and by defining the projection you can modify it. Having it defined makes it available as a function. This way you could place your points as svg circles:

```
svg.append("circle").attr("r",5).attr("transform", function() {return "translate(" + projection([-75,43]) + ")";});
```

That should drop a circle on the rough vicinity of New York. You could then bind data that had the "lat" and "long" as attributes, in which case it would look like this:

```
 svg.selectAll("circles.points")
.data(yourData)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("r",5)
.attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + projection([d.long,d.lat]) + ")";});
```

The projection function takes [long,lat] array and returns a [x,y] array, which fits fine into transform,translate() syntax, or you could split the array for x and y values.

The example below places polys, lines and points, and takes the points from a csv and projects them onto a map, but notice that it transforms the g element and appends an a circle onto that element (you might also want a label or other aspects to a site, all of which would be appended to that projected g element):

https://gist.github.com/4414107
http://bl.ocks.org/d/4414107/